# UITapGestureRecognizer not working if tapping same location for two separate UIImageViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm attaching a UITapGestureRecognizer to two different imageviews that will occupy the same space but at different times.  Currently I'm using a flip transition that when an image is tapped it flips to the image on the other side like a card flipping over. I can get the first image to flip just fine but once flipped the second image doesn't respond at all when being tapped.  I used a `print("tapped")` to see if the second image is even getting the tap gesture but it isn't. This is the function I used to add the tap gestures:

```
  func addTapGestures() {

    jokerImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    vendettaImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(flipView(_:)))
    jokerImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    vendettaImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UITapGestureRecognizer` is a distinct object. It can only be added to one element at a time.

So in your code, you add it to `jokerImageView` and then immediately *remove* it and add it to `vendettaImageView`.

You either need to create 2 instances of `UITapGestureRecognizer`, or you need to add it to `joker` after it has been "used" by `vendetta` and vice-versa.

**Edit:** Instead of creating a 2nd gesture recognizer, you could try this:

```
func flipView(_ sender: Any) -> Void {

    // view flip code goes here

    // then
    if let g = sender as? UIGestureRecognizer {
        if g.view == vendettaImageView {
            jokerImageView.addGestureRecognizer(g)
        } else {
            vendettaImageView.addGestureRecognizer(g)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, i'll just add another tap gesture recognizer